# Adding vector representing direction to object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bezier

I'm trying to make a simple VR movement script using teleportation. I used three empty `GameObjects` to generate with them Quadratic `BezzierCurve`. `p0` is a `GameObject` inside the player; it's moving with the player. My problem is that points (`Gameobject`s) aren't relative to player. When `p0` is in position `0, 0, 0`, the script works fine; but when I hooked it up to player and I move the player around scene, these points are not relative to player. I think I messed up with some basic stuff.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class settingPos : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform tf;
    public GameObject p0, p1, p2; 

    // 3 empty GameObjects to paste them into QuadraticBezzier Script which uses it for 
    // generate bezzier curve. p0 is gameObject inside player, it is moving with player

    public float UpForce; //simply value for scaling Bezzier curve
    Vector3 [] dir= new Vector3[2];

    void Update () 
    {

        dir[0] = p0.transform.position;
        Vector3 temp = transform.rotation * Vector3.forward;
        temp *= UpForce;
        dir[0] += temp;

        dir[1] = new Vector3(dir[0].x * 2, 0, dir[0].z * 2); // This is end point of bezzier 
                                                             // curve. I mentioned that 
                                                             // distance between end-point 
                                                             // and height of bezzier curve 
                                                             // was this same as start-point 
                                                             // and height.

        p1.transform.position = dir[0];
        p2.transform.position = dir[1];
    }
}
```

[Pretty short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p643N.png)

It should look this same, but in other position.

[This shows my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk9yt.png)

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what is going wrong? What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Not sure it it was a typo but in the `temp *= UpForace;` line, `UpForace` was actually declared as `UpForce`.

Comment: I just moved a litle point0 in X axis. (diffrence between two screens)

Comment: Don't know if I understand correctly, but maybe try to set .localPosition instead of position. If the object you want to move relative to player is already a child of the player, then this should work.

Comment: Wow, awesome it work now. Thank you